# Extension of harmonic function with bounded $L^{2}$ norm

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Let $h:D\setminus \{0\}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a harmonic function, where $D$ is the unit disc in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$, with bounded $L^{2}$ norm, i.e. $||h||_{L^{2}(D)}^{2}=\int_{D}|h|^{2}(x,y)dxdy < \infty$. Is it possible to extend $h$ harmonically to the whole disc $D$?

Roman

Comment: In which sense do you want to extend this function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function $h(x,y)=\log(x^2+y^2)$ shows that the answer is no.